# Ansible: manipulate variable names

Tags: variables, ansible

I am using a list of variables (under `to_install`) contained in `hosts_vars` file to feed my `deploy.yml` playbook.
My `hosts_vars`:

```
---
clients:
  cl1:
    to_install:
    - banana 8.1
    - Firefox 46.0.1
    to_uninstall:
    - null
```

My playbook:

```
- name: Deploy
  hosts: win_clones
  vars_files:
    - ./hosts_vars
  tasks:
    - name: Fetching and copying the file on the client ...
      win_get_url:
        url: 'ftp://172.20.0.5/choco-repo/{{ item }}'
        dest: 'C:\Test\{{ item }}'
      with_items: "{{ clients[machine].to_install }}"
    - name: Installing the package ...
      win_chocolatey:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: present
        with_items: "{{ clients[machine].to_install }}"
```

I run this play with the following command:

```
ansible-playbook deploy.yml -e machine=cl1
```

For the first task of my playbook I use `win_get_url` and I would like to transform my variables names into:

```
banana8.1.nupkg
Firefox46.0.1.nupkg
```

For the second task I use `win_chocolatey` and it is enough to pass only the names of the variables (without the version number):

```
banana
Firefox
```

I guess the magic should happens in 
`with_items: "{{clients[machine].to_install }}"`. How can I do that in ansible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex_replace in order to do that.

This:

```
tasks:
  - debug: msg="{{ item | regex_replace(' ', '') }}.nupkg"
    with_items: "{{ clients[machine].to_install }}"
```

Will print:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [win_clones] => (item=banana 8.1) => {
    "item": "banana 8.1", 
    "msg": "banana8.1.nupkg"
}
ok: [win_clones] => (item=Firefox 46.0.1) => {
    "item": "Firefox 46.0.1", 
    "msg": "Firefox46.0.1.nupkg"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for the first task. How would I do the second one, i.e. to remove the version number to have the name only?

Comment: Exactly like I did for the first one, by playing with regex_replace. It will be no fun if you had nothing left to do right? If you cant find a solution I'll help you, but I think you can figure this out.

Comment: Well, It works just by using `debug: msg="{{ item | regex_replace(' ', '') }}"` but it seems kind of strange. Doesn't this just remove the space? So I should get banana8.1 and Firefox46.0.1

Comment: Yes, that's really strange, you should have banana8.1 indeed.

Comment: No, I get `"msg": "banana8.1"` and `"msg": "Firefox46.0.1"` as expected (ansible 2.1.0.0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115735/discussion-between-diegus-and-michael-bitard).